# angular defining/loading/configuring the modules

Tags: angularjs

What are the differences between the 2 ways to write the code below in terms of functionality?

I am adhering to this [code writing style](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y022).

I tried in my code but the second form broke the code, I refrained from posting the whole code to focus on the main part. Thanks

```
var myApp = angular.module('MainMenuCtrl', ['ngAnimate']);
myApp.controller('MainMenuCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', MainMenu]);

 angular
    .module('MainMenuCtrl', ['ngAnimate'])
    .controller('MainMenuCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', MainMenu]);
```

Comment: the only way the second form would break your code is if some code you haven't posted here used the `myApp` variable.  The point of using the second form is that the variable isn't strictly necessary, and providing it has the downside of possible naming collisions, but no upside.

Comment: Check your `MainMenu` function and make sure that `$scope` is the first argument and that `$http` is the second argument. Any other order will  break your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second approach is more modular since you can grab a part of it and immediately put it into another project without having to see if the `app` variable, which happens to be a global, matches the project you insert it into.

Also you can wrap all components in an IIFE and include "use strict" without forcing it on any other scripts in page.

Also build and scaffolding tools don't need to set any variables

```
// in one file
;(function(){

    "use strict";
     // var app wouldn't be available in the next file if it was used here

     angular
        .module('MainMenuCtrl', ['ngAnimate'])
        .controller('MainMenuCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', MainMenu]);
)}();

// in another file
;(function(){    
    "use strict";

     angular
        .module('MainMenuCtrl')
        .controller('AnotherCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',AnotherCtrl]);

)}();
```